# HTTPS on Amazon EC2 for OwnCloud

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, https, amazon-ec2, dns

I have a question which I hope somebody can answer for me.

My situation: I have an Ubuntu Server running Apache2 on a EC2 Amazon instance, which is serving an OwnCloud instance.

My goal: I want to deploy HTTPS on this instance. I already configured the security group to allow HTTPS traffic from anywhere (as the server should be accessible from anywhere on the internet). We already have a domain name bar.com registered at another domain hosting company. But we want to point foo.bar.com to this owncloud installation.

My questions:

1) Which IP-address do I use to configure the DNS at this domain hosting company. Because the public ip-address and public DNS of the EC2 instance is renewed every time the instance restarts.

2) How do I generate the SSL certificate for HTTPS configuration of Apache2? More specifically, which common name (CN) do I need to put in the certificate. Because the public dns of the EC2 instance is changing on every restart. I think if I put the foo.bar.com CN in the certificate that the browser will throw a certificate error once the user gets redirected from foo.bar.com -> .compute.amazonaws.com, am I right?

In short: how do I deploy https on a EC2 instance at Amazon AWS with a dns at a third party domain name service?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! This shouldn't be here but on another of the SE sites like askubuntu.com of something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To deal with the changing public ip address you've got two options, first and (for simple situations, best) go to the Elastic Ip Page, get an eip and associate it with your instance, this association and hence public IP will hang around even after start/stop. You can even move the eip over to a different machine if you need to. This option is very cheap (you only get charged for an eip if its not attached to a started server). You're then safe to point your dns at the eip. The alternative option is much more powerful and that is to use elb (load balancing) but it also involves a fair amount more work to setup.
2. I assume if you're asking about cn's you dont really want a "how to" on creating an ssl cert (please correct me if I'm wrong). For the cn you just use the domain name - it doesn't matter what ip address the name resolves to the cert is for the domain. If you have your own domain to point at your eip you dont need to care about the machines public hostname. A user will never see it.